# How is a comment categorized in JS?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments, theory

In JavaScript syntax, we know of stuff like:

- `+`, `=`, `,`, `(...)` being **operators**
- `var`, `let`, `function`, `for` being **keywords**
- `1`, `"string"`, being **literals**
- `1+1` being an **expression** containing operators and literals
  and
- `var myVar = 1+1;` being a **statement** containing keywords and expressions

How would you group `//` and `/* ... */`? I feel like it is an operator, but I don't see it in the [Operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

I will soon give a training for beginners in JavaScript and I would like to be as rigorous as I can

Comment: [Section 11.4 of the grammar.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-comments) Comments are like white space; they don't do anything functionally but they do serve to separate source text characters in the tokenization process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are their own category, and a very high-level syntax production. You can see this in [the lexical structure overview](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar) in the specification, and in the section on [comments](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-comments).

Answer (score 1):

Comment symbols, just as `;`,`,`,`{` and others, are [lexical primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) and considered to occupy a high-level category, which is simply called Comments.